# Problem with new installation of Flutter windows 10

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I followed the steps in installing flutter on windows 10. At first, it gives me error messages regarding SDK not downloaded. I downloaded Android Studio to help with that and now, the Android Studio cannot create a flutter project.

Also, if I run any flutter command on my CMD, it flashes a new CMD and then it does not show any response. Please help.

Comment: Please post any error messages to help narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Start Android Studio.
- Open plugin preferences (Preferences > Plugins on macOS, File > Settings > Plugins on Windows & Linux).
- Select Marketplace, select the Flutter plugin and click Install.
- Click Yes when prompted to install the Dart plugin.
- Click Restart when prompted.
  Reference: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor